# Missing file for compilation

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, aes, header-files

I am trying to cross compile a C code which uses a header file mcrypt.h. I am compiling my code in Ubuntu distribution and my target is an openwrt distribution. I am getting the below error while cross compiling:

```
fatal error: mcrypt.h: No such file or directory
#include <mcrypt.h>
                   ^
```

Below is the C code used for AES encryption : https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364
The problem is that I coudn't find out how to use the Mcrypt API given here : http://linux.die.net/man/3/mcrypt

I'm Stuck at this point.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You will have install libmcrypt **-dev** package

Comment: Yes but I tried to install libmcrypt -dev package for openwrt which is my distribution target by `sudo make menuconfig` to choose the package to install but I didn't find it.